# Batch file rename multiple files only echos the result

Tags: windows, batch-file

I was having an issue with creating a batch file (.bat) to rename multiple files in the same directory based on specific parameters. In order to make it happen for multiple files I had to add an incremental value to it.

From research(mostly here) I pieced together the below command, but whatever I do I cannot actually get to do it. It just echos what's supposed to do and when I remove the echo from before 'ren' it says bad syntax.

```
@echo off
CD C:\FolderPath\
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set /a count=0
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('dir /b /od *.txt') do (
echo ren CDFF_%date:~-4,4%%date:~-10,2%%date:~-7,2%_%hr%%time:~3,2%%time:~6,2%%time:~9,2%_!count!.txt
set /a count+=1
)
```

Comment: @Tomalak - Read the question more carefully. The OP says it results in a syntax error if ECHO is removed.

Comment: @dbenham Oh, you're right. Removing comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the first parameter to ren command (the file to rename):

```
ren "%%a" "CDFF_%date:~-4,4%%date:~-10,2%%date:~-7,2%_%hr%%time:~3,2%%time:~6,2%%time:~9,2%_!count!.txt"
```

So the whole code is:

```
@echo off   
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

CD C:\FolderPath\
set /a count=0

for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('dir /b /od *.txt') do (
   echo ren "%%a" "CDFF_%date:~-4,4%%date:~-10,2%%date:~-7,2%_%hr%%time:~3,2%%time:~6,2%%time:~9,2%_!count!.txt"
   set /a count+=1
)
```

Please note it will not work for files with weird names. Eg. "File( name.txt"

Comment: +1, But why shouldn't it work with poison characters? The quotes should protect against poison characters.

Comment: I tried this and I got a "The system cannot find the path specified" so I removed the 'CD' command just to test it with files in the folder the *.bat file is in and I still only get it to echo what it's supposed to do.

Comment: Ok. scratch that. it works.

to make it easy I just copied the code over, but I failed to realize that even though I added the parameter after 'ren' I failed to remove the echo before it. 

thanks

Answer (score 0):

`ren` requires the input filname as its first argument. Hence your syntax error.

Here is an alternative implementation:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set FOLDER=%1
set DATE=%date:~-4,4%%date:~-10,2%%date:~-7,2%_%hr%%time:~3,2%%time:~6,2%%time:~9,2%
set /a count=0

for /r %FOLDER% %%a in (*.txt) do (
    ren "%%a" CDFF_%DATE%_!count!.txt
    set /a count += 1
)
```

call as

```
rename.bat C:\FolderPath
```

Comment: Thanks. I might be mistaken but the way i'm reading this the .bat file needs to be called with the target path.

in my case the target path never changes and the .bat file cannot be situated in the target path hence why I tried writing it as I did. (probably should have added that in the initial description)

Comment: That's a special case already handled by the `for /r` loop. If you omit the argument, then `%1` will be empty, which means `FOLDER` will be empty, at which point `for /r` assumes the current directory.